# How to stay on top child in Firebase Database Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some Database in Firebase:

[image: My Firebase Database]

I want to child "bestresult" in "Test 1" stay on top and new childs add after him. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child nodes in the Firebase console are shown in alphabetical order. There is no way to change this.

To control the order of child nodes in your application code, you can use the `orderBy...` methods shown in the documentation on [sorting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data).

Comment: Oh yes, in alphabetical order. So I can start the child name with '*' and new children will be added after. :)
thanks ^^